# Physical sunscreen high SPF vs high active ingredient percentage

Tags: face, spf-sun-protection-factor, sunscreen-sunblock

I'm looking at two products:

- Product A contains active ingredients Zinc Oxide at 9.0%, and Titanium Dioxide at 7.0% for 113g.  It has SPF 45.
- Product B contains an active ingredient Zinc Oxide at 20% for 100g. It has SPF 40.

Both products are mostly naturally derived and hardly contain any chemicals - paraben free, DEA free, non-nano, etc. However I read that zinc oxide is better at blocking UVA than titanium dioxide - and here is where my confusion lies:

Which product is healthier (i.e. no long-term harmful effects on skin, and better sun protection) to use? Product A with higher SPF, or Product B with higher amount of zinc oxide?

Thank you